# "Could not determine customer compid" USER_ERROR in netsuite sandbox

Tags: netsuite

I have a User event which calls a restlet using nlapiRequestURL() method. The URL, headers and authorization seems fine but it returns an error message saying - "Could not determine customer compid". Has anyone had the same issue earlier or know how to work around with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We see this occassionally when a Suitelet or Restlet URL isn't specific enough for NetSuite to know which company is trying to call the URL.  The script id by itself is not enough to know the company if the user is not currently logged in to NetSuite.

You can add `&compid=<YOUR NETSUITE ACCOUNT NUMBER>` to the the URL to let NetSuite know which company is trying to call the specific URL.

Comment: This looked promising, but in our case it turned out to be that the password of the account that was calling the restlet had expired or become invalid.  After entering a new password, everything started working again, no compid parameter required.  (The error messages returned by their service were spectacularly unhelpful.)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this on because I had the same issue, you'll get the same error if you're hitting a sandbox and not capitalizing the `SB` in `nlauth_account`.

Eg `NLAuth nlauth_account=XXXXXXX_SB1` instead of `NLAuth nlauth_account=XXXXXXX_sb1`.

Comment: @CameronBelt This is one of several things that can cause the same error message, you'd need to go through all the possible options(which are not listed anywhere). Just because this wasn't the issue for you, doesn't mean its not the issue for someone else

Answer (score 0):

We did face this issue, clearing browser cookies solved in most cases.

Sometimes the problem was persistent for about few hours and got fixed on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NLAuth, be sure you use commas (not spaces) to separate the account, email, and signature fields.  Using spaces gave me this error.